# Count On Bigest tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my problem is caused when i try to get the COUNT of a consult return a big amount of records (example 500.000):

Example:

```
$limit = ' LIMIT 0,30';
$ResultQuery = mysql_query("
    SELECT id, name, description, date 
    FROM products 
    WHERE name 
    LIKE 'dog%'".$limit);

$CountQuery = mysql_query("
    SELECT COUNT(id) 
    FROM products 
    WHERE name LIKE 'dog%'");

while ($Product = mysql_fetch_assoc($ResultQuery)) { [...]
```

NOTE: The Use of COUNT(id) its more fast (in my case) than use mysql_num_rows of $ResultQuery.

If i see what is doing the server using the MySQL Administrator, i see 3 seconds make the 1º Query (the limit), one second "sending data", and 143 seconds "sending data" of the 2º Query.

I read more articles about this problem its caused because for get the count of the query, need to scan ALL ROWS (without the limit) of the Query.

Not exists any method or mode to bypass this problem? Any method to extract the count of rows with big number of results?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you set an `index` to your `name` field?

Comment: Yes, all return fields (except description) are index

Comment: How many records do you have with 'dog%'? If there are more records that half of the table, index will be ineffective and even slower than usual fullscan

Comment: How are the indexes set? If you've set an index similar to (col1, col2, ..., name), it can't be used for this query. Please post your indexes as well as the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE name LIKE 'dog%'`

Comment: id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra

1 | SIMPLE | products | ALL | name | NULL | NULL | NULL | 22160980 | Using where


name are a FULL TEXT index, id INT(11) BTREE and date is int(11)

Comment: As a small preformance tip, use `COUNT(*)` and not `COUNT(id)`. They do the same (aasuming that `id` is the PK and thus not nullable) but MySQL seems to perform better with the first (I've fallen into that trap).

Comment: Do you have an index on `name`? Can you provide the table definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra 
>   
> 1 | SIMPLE | products | ALL | name | NULL | NULL | NULL | 22160980 | Using where

You can see from the above that the index "name" is not being used. And the reason for that is the following.

You are using Full Text index on the name column which is only useful for Full-text search queries
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

If you do not do any full-text searches, delete that index and create another index as suggested above

> CREATE INDEX `idx_name` ON products (name)

This will create a BTREE index on name which will then be used in your search query. Note that this index will not be useful if you do a like query with '%' at the beginning. For example

> SELECT count(id) FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%dogs'

will not use the index.

Comment: OK, i try it. The LIKE its a example, i need the FT index because use MATCH to search.
I assume only need "extra" index in field are NOT index or FULLTEXT no?

Comment: Do you need to run both LIKE and MATCH queries? Also, are you having any problems optimizing your MATCH query?

Answer (score 1):

My best bet is you're not having set your indexes up correctly. By the looks of it, you haven't set up a proper index for your `name` field and that causes MySQL to go through every row (more than 22 000 000) to look for `'dog%'`.

I suggest you try using a regular index and benchmark the results

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_name` ON products (name)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$count =  mysql_num_rows($ResultQuery);
```

Comment: This not give me the TOTAL RESULTS (pages), give the count of results in the first query..

Comment: OP specifically mentioned this approach to be slower.

Comment: Ok OP, i got it. And @gilden, you are wrong, OP was referring to the second query's count.